# Alternative (to Axis 1.4) WSDL to Java 14 client generator that supports "RPC/encoded" format

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, code-generation, axis

## The Problems

### Axis 1.4 & JDK 14

I'm trying to update our application from Java 8 to Java 14, and in doing so, I discovered that Axis 1.4 seems to generate client code that is no longer valid for the newer version of Java.

The issue boils down to Axis' use of `com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider`... when running on JDK 14, this throws a `NoClassDefFoundError`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/net/ssl/internal/ssl/Provider
```

### RPC/encoded WSDLs

The WSDls that I'm trying to parse are from a 3rd party, and unfortunately they are `RPC/encoded`, which I didn't know until now, is a legacy, seemingly no longer supported, WSDL format.

Thus, my journey to find an alternative to Axis 1.4 - which gladly handles the legacy `RPC/encoded` format due to it being a very outdated library itself.

---

## The Attempted Solutions

### Looked For Replacement Jar

My first thought, was to research whether or not the `com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider` lives in a jar in maven central... similar to how some of the other built-in packages were moved to external jars in Java's more recent versions. I found that the package was removed as part of [JDK-8218932](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8218932), but my research fell short, and wasn't able to find a recommended dependency that I could use in it's place.

### Other WSDL to Java Methods

Next I tried to use some of the other WSDL to Java generators that I found... Unfortunately, they all seem not to support the legacy `RPC/encoded` format that this 3rd party WSDL is.

#### javaws-maven-plugin

```
[ERROR] "Use of SOAP Encoding is not supported.
SOAP extension element on line 46 in file:/<path>/wsdl/kas.wsdl has use="encoded" "
```

#### cxf-codegen-plugin

```
Execution kas of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.3.7:wsdl2java failed:
Rpc/encoded wsdls are not supported with CXF
```

#### Axis 2

Didn't bother attempting, because it clearly states [on their website](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/Axis2-rpc-support.html):

> Note that Axis2 currently does not support the rpc/encoded style.

### Ask The 3rd Party to Update WSDLs

I plan on reaching out to the 3rd party to see if they could update their WSDLs... however, they seem to currently be generated with Axis 1.3 as they have:

```
<!--WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.3
```

I'm not sure how to present to them exactly what they need to do in order to switch their system to a more recent style of WSDL. Additionally, I don't have much confidence in them being willing to change since they have multiple different versions we integrate with, and this would affect all their other clients that have integrations.

---

## Thanks

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm facing the same problem right now. How did it turn out for you?

Comment: I was unable to get the 3rd party to update their SOAP endpoint, as they were unsure how to stop using "RPC/encoded"... So for the time being, we are stuck on Java 11, until we switch to the third party's REST endpoint. Please advise if you find a working solution!

Comment: We contacted the service consumer. He told us they could use rpc/literal for over a decade now and were surprised we still used rpc/encoded. Long story short: We're switching to rpc/literal and thus can use CXF. => No pure technical solution here